# determining if a group of nodes can be treated as an isolated subgraph of a directed acyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a directed acyclic graph. I'm trying to determine if I can group a segment of this graph and treat it as a single node within the directed acyclic graph. This single node can have multiple inputs or outputs.

Is there an algorithmic solution that can help me determine this?

For an illustration, here's a simple graph, where all multi-node groups that exclude b would be treated as invalid and all other groups would be valid:

```
    a -> b -> c
         |
         v
         d
```

Comment: A group of nodes is valid if there is no path between two nodes of the group that includes a node not from the group. In your example, you *can* have a group that only includes c and d.

Comment: ah yes that would work, that phrasing is useful, i could probably try and implement that but it seems expensive, in that i have to look at every path from every node in the group.

Comment: @tempaccount You wouldn't have to enumerate all paths, just do DFS twice, once forward from the group nodes, once backward, then verify that the intersection contains no non-group nodes.

Comment: what do you mean by doing dfs 'backward' here?

Comment: In the graph where all of the arcs are reversed.